# Spring MVC - Dynamic Web Forms - Form Builder - Design Issue

Tags: java, spring, forms, hibernate, formbuilder

I need advise on db as well as architecture side.

I am developing an application, which uses form builder approach for certain areas. E.g. User Registration, where apart from some basic fields for user, extra fields can be configured by admin:

[image: Form Builder Example]

I have few tables in the database which will store the meta data for these newly created fields:

```
FIELDS_TXN
______________
F_ID
F_NAME
F_ORDER
F_TYPE_ID

FIELD_TYPE_MST
______________
F_TYPE_ID
F_TYPE

FIELD_OPTIONS_TXN
______________
F_OPTION_ID
F_OPTION_VALUE
F_FIELD_ID
```

(This is a very rough db design)

Now I know what new fields I need to show in the form, but how do I store this extra data?

For example default fields for User are first name, last name and email

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_txn")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Now if admin adds or configures more fields like Date of Birth, Address, City, Country, Pincode for the users, how do I store values for these fields?

One approach I have in mind is create a table e.g. user_custom_fields? But how to dynamic hibernate mapping for custom fields for dynamically created table??

Is it a good approach for building dynamic forms in web application?

Comment: Nice question. I have been developing a CRM web application which requires such features. In this moment I've some ideas.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more information on how you built the initial interface for this design and what technologies you used? I am trying to build something similar and don't know where to start, so any feedback would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the approach of saving all fields as a "field" in your DB. Say you have a table "Fields", the field that the admin adds, will add an entry in this table. Similarly create forms, The entire application approach can be such a way that all fields are created when the application starts up. Might Help !!